# How to load javascript function in window.onload after some delay

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, firefox3.6

I have couple of functions that should be triggered after some delay in onload event. It works fine in chrome but not in Firefox.

```
function foo() {
    // javascript code
}

window.onload = setTimeout(foo, delay);

function bar() {
    // javascript code
}

window.onload = setTimeout(bar, delay);
```

If I remove the delay, 'bar' gets invoked in Firefox and 'foo' and 'bar' get invoked in chrome. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised both functions get invoked in any browser.  But you might have better luck with something like:

```
function foo() {
    // javascript code
    setTimeout(bar, additionalDelay);
}

function bar() {
    // javascript code
}

window.onload = function() { setTimeout(foo, delay); };
```

Edit:  Nevermind, I see why both of the timeouts execute.  When you do something like:

`window.onload = setTimeout(bar, delay);`

...you are not actually setting `window.onload` to execute your function after a delay.  Instead this is immediately invoking `setTimeout()` to schedule your function call, and assigning the result (a handle to the scheduled function invocation) to `window.onload`.  This is not correct, and will probably cause a runtime error in some browsers when they try to invoke `window.onload` as a function.

What you want to do instead is assign a function to `window.onload`, like:

```
window.onload = function() { 
    setTimeout(foo, delay); 
    setTimeout(bar, delay);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use jQuery with sth like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() { /* your code */ });
```

or

```
$(window).load(function() { /* your code */ });
```

jQuery automatically adds functions to stack, and run them all once event is triggered.

If you want do it with only JS, you can make array of functions to trigger:

```
function a() {
        alert('a');
    }

    function b() {
        alert('b');
    }

    var arr = new Array(a, b);

    window.onload = function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            setTimeout(arr[i], 1000);
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The idea of the function array is quite neat. If you add some `var arr = [];` and `arr.push(a); arr.push(b);` it'll be perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the timeout in a function:

```
window.onload = function(delay) {
                  setTimeout(foo, delay); 
                  setTimeout(bar, delay); 
                };
```

Comment: @Koooilnc Thanks for the tip. Can you tell us how to do this dynamically, since based on some naming conventions there is usually a javascript function for all items in a radio button (e.g. I might have 2 or 3 or 4 or many choices).

Comment: @Kalpana not sure what you mean: `window.onload = [somefunction]` means: start `somefunction` after the document had loaded. After that you can use functions for clicking radio buttons etc. If you want them to trigger a page reload with a certain `delay`, you can try to put a parameter in the html (`thisorthat.html?delay=10`). Search SO for the way to use parameters, plenty of answers to be found.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two base errors in your code. First of all, if you want to pass a function as argument you need to write the function name without parenthesis; if you add the parenthesis the function will be *executed* right then. See an example:

```
function foo(){
    alert("I am foo");
}
function bar(){
    alert("I am bar");
}

setTimeout(foo, 5000);
setTimeout(bar(), 10000);
```

Secondly, if you assign a value to the `.onload` attribute with the `=` operator you'll overwrite its previous value, just like `a = 3` overwrites previous the value of `a`.

```
function foo(){
    alert("I am foo");
}
function bar(){
    alert("I am bar");
}
window.onload = foo;
window.onload = bar;
```

From what I grasp, your main problem is to be able to *add* rather than *replace* event handlers. As usual, there isn't a universal API you can safely use in all browsers. If you are using a framework or library, it probably provides a cross-browser mechanism. Otherwise, you need to find or write your own. In the past, I've used this in several projects:

- http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/10/add-event2/

... although it's not been updated since 2005 so I'd make sure it works properly in recent browsers.